# How to submit data to multiple tables in the same form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 tables: listings and listings_specifications

Listings table

- id
- type
- status
- location
- specifications_id

Listings_specifications table

- id
- listing_id
- swimming_pool
- water_well

I need to select the specifications (checkboxes) on the same form with which I add a listing. I have created all the forms, views, models, controllers but I think I got some logic wrong.

Listing.php model

protected $table = 'listings';

```
public function contact()
{
   return $this->BelongsTo('contacts');
}
public function specifications()
{
   return $this->BelongsTo('listings_specifications');
}
```

Specification.php model

protected $table = 'listings_specifications';

```
public function listings()
{
   return $this->BelongsTo('listings');
}
```

ListingsController.php (where the data gets saved in the database)

```
$listing = new Listing;
                $contact = new Contact;
                $listing->status = Input::get('status');
                $listing->listingfor = Input::get('listingfor');
                $listing->propertystatus = Input::get('propertystatus');
                $listing->propertytype = Input::get('propertytype');
                $listing->userid = Auth::user()->id;
                $listing->location = Input::get('location');
                $listing->contact_id = $contact_id;

                $listing->save();

                $specifications = Specification::find($id);

                if( $listings->save() ) {
                        $specifications = new Specification;
                        $specifications->listing_id = $id;
                        $specifications->swimming_pool       = Input::get('swimming_pool');
                        $specifications->water_front      = Input::get('water_front');
                        $specifications->save();
                }
```

I'm getting this error: Undefined variable: id

Where did I go wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some logic errors.

First of all, you are never setting `$id` anywhere, but that's okay because you really don't need it.

Remove the `$specifications = Specification::find($id);` line because that's not doing anything.

Then change your last section to something like this...

```
            if( $listings->save() ) {
                    $specifications = new Specification;
                    $specifications->swimming_pool       = Input::get('swimming_pool');
                    $specifications->water_front      = Input::get('water_front');
                    $listing->specifications()->save($specifications);
            }
```

`$listing->specifications()->save($specifications);` will automatically save the new specification with the correct `listing_id` for you.

Modify your `Listing` model's `specifications` relationship to...

```
public function specifications()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Specification');
}
```

I'm assuming here one listing can have many specifications.  If not, you can easily just change that to a `hasOne`.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error upon submission

Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Comment: Oh, I see, your relationship has been setup wrong.  I'll update the answer to include the fix for that.  Two relationships can't belong to eachother unless it's a belongsToMany.  Here, a specification belongs to a listing and a listing can have many specifications.

Comment: Yes, a Listing can have many listings_specifications. I changed my code but I'm still getting the same error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Thank you for correcting my db relationships.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo $listings->save() should be $listing->save() but now I'm back at the error: Undefined variable: id

Comment: I declared $id = 0 and that fixed the error, I hope that was a good move. But overall, I'm getting a new error on submissions: Class 'listings_specifications' not found. As far as I know, I have 1 specifications() method in Specification.php model

Comment: Ohhhh I'm so sorry, it's apparently been a long day for me.  Check the updated answer where I corrected you in your specifications relationship.  You are supposed to send the name of the model, not the table.

Comment: This is great. It worked. Now a new row is being inserted into listings_specifications with the correct listing_id. But there's one thing missing, I forgot to mention specifications_id in listings table in order to associate it with listings_specifications. How do I pass the correct id of specs into $listing->specifications_id?

Comment: That column shouldn't be necessary.  You only need a foreign key on one of the tables to link them both back and forth.

Comment: I thought so, I was starting to confuse myself. Man, you are awesome, thank you very very much.

Answer (score 1):

You use `$id` in the line `$specifications = Specification::find($id);` but you don't define it before.